# Can I declare a vec3 outside the shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, shader

Just wondering if there's a way to create a Vec3 outside the shaders. For example in my program I want to have something like:

```
function()
{
  vec3 a =  vec3 (x, y, z)
}
```

But at the moment I'm getting the error 'vec3 is undefined'. Is there a library I can include, or some other way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a .h file that comes with OpenGL Red book 8th edition called [vmath.h](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/blob/master/include/vmath.h) that does what you want. You can include it in your source file and use it almost as if you were in a shader.

Answer (score -1):

You can. It works just as how you think it works. In your example code did you forget to add the ";"?

Comment: Nope, if I try to make the vector vec3 vec; I get two errors,     ' error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'vec'' and 'error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int'

Comment: Works on my end. I have 

void main(){
   vec3 vec = vec3(0.1,0.5,0.9);
   frag = vec4(vec.rgb,1.0);
}

using #version 330

Comment: @sgtHale: Though worded poorly, I believe Luke4792 is referring to using `vec3` from C++ code. @Luke4792: If this is your actual question, then I would suggest looking into [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) - it is a very close fit for all of the GLSL data types in C++/Obj-C++.